# Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius

Tags: javascript, openweathermap, converters

I need some help for an web app I make for a school pjoject.
I want to convert the temperature from Fahrenheit to celsius.

Now I wrote this code:

```
$("#desc").html('Sky: ' + data.weather[0].description);


var fahr = data.main.temp + " °F";
var cels = ("fahr" - 32) * 5 / 9 + " °C";

$("#temp").html(data.main.temp + " °F");

$("#celButt").on("click", function() {
$("#temp").html(cels);});

$("#fahrButt").on("click", function() {
$("#temp").html(fahr);});
```

If I click te button to convert the data I get this as result:

NaN °C

Someone who can help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: Change `("fahr" - 32) * 5 / 9 + " °C"` to `(data.main.temp - 32) * 5 / 9 + " °C"`. Don't know what you were trying to do by subtracting a number from a string!

Comment: I don't understand why there is string `("fahr" - 32)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add or subtract or divide or multiply a string, which, by the time you try to calculate Celsius, is exactly what you are doing.

You are trying to subtract the number 32 from the string "80 °F" for example, which doesn't make sense.

Instead, you can do the following :

```
var fahr = data.main.temp + " °F";
var cels = (data.main.temp - 32) * 5 / 9 + " °C";
```

Also you may as well change :

```
 $("#temp").html(data.main.temp + " °F");
```

To

```
 $("#temp").html(fahr);
```

For increased readability and to keep things consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "fahr" try var cels = (data.main.temp - 32) * 5 / 9 + " °C";